# Preparing a service to use upstart and systemD (compatibility)

Tags: upstart, systemd

We are currently building an [cool open source tool](https://github.com/uditalias/swamp) to be used as a linux service. so I begin writing an upstart script, But then I wondered, if debian/ubuntu world is moving to systemD, should I write a script for systemD? Upstart? Both? Are they compatible? If not, how do we handle the transition period (which I suppose would take a couple of years.. )

I'll be glad for advice and best practice about this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is wondering [here](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316) is the blog about the announcement that Ubuntu will follow Debian's discission on changing from upstart to systemd.

---

The thing is: if you code something and want a larger user base than Ubuntu users it might already be wise to always include a systemd script. [Redhat](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd), [SUSE](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aSystemd), [Gentoo](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Systemd), [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) already (can) use systemd.

If Ubuntu is the sole target you could stick with upstart and deal with systemd when the time is there to worry about systemd. That is going to take at least 6 more months so there is plenty of time.

And if you are lucky someone creates a conversion tool to automatically create a systemd script from an upstart script.

---

Basically: what ever you want do that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard one to answer because the developers have only just decided on their broad strategic approach to the shift to systemd.

This discussion took place at the Ubuntu Developer Summit last month, but I'm afraid I can't find a link to the video debate.

It looks like they are going to try to convert the work currently done by upstart into systemd tasks, almost like a wrapper to upstart. But that's just the first step to make sure that users aren't disrupted by the changeover, which is going to be done over quite an extended period of time, bit by bit.

As far as I understood the discussion systemd scripts will work normally, and upstart tasks will be made to work with systemd, so perhaps you would be better doing it all as a systemd task from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Make your daemon so simple you can write both an upstart job and systemd service in 10 minutes! But yeah, I would say both. If you give me an example of how to start up the swamp daemon, I could write the Upstart job for you.